# Selective reshaping of 3d array to 2d array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, reshape

I'm working with a 3d array of vectors, and having trouble reshaping properly. 
My dimensions correspond to quantities as follows:

0 = vector (3)

1 = point (4)

2 = polyline (2)

So this can be interpreted as 2 polylines that each contain 4 points, and each point has a vector. I want to reshape to a 2d matrix that is (3, 8).

The original array is:

```
poly_array = array([[[-0.707, 0.0],
                      [-0.371, 0.0],
                      [0.371, 0.0],
                      [0.707, 0.0]],
                     [[0.0, -0.707],
                      [0.0, 0.0],
                      [0.0, 0.707],
                      [0.0, 0.0]],
                     [[0.707, 0.707],
                      [0.928, 1.0],
                      [0.928, 0.707],
                      [0.707, 0.0]]])
```

so if I'm looking at ordered points along the first polyline, I would run:

```
for i in range(4):
    print poly_array[:,i,0]
```

or for ordered points along the second polyline:

```
for i in range(4):
    print poly_array[:,i,1]
```

If I reshape this way:

```
new_dim = shape(poly_array)[1] * shape(poly_array)[2]
new_array = poly_array.reshape(3, new_dim)
```

But this orders the vectors as taking one from each polyline (i.e., pt0-polyline0, pt0-polyline1, pt1-polyline0, pt1-polyline1, etc.)

```
In: print new_array[:, 0]
Out: [-0.707  0.     0.707]

In: print new_array[:, 1]
Out: [ 0.    -0.707  0.707]
```

But I want

```
In: print new_array[:, 1]
Out: [-0.371  0.     0.928]
```

How can I reshape so that it loops through all the vectors corresponding to points (along axis 1) for a given polyline before the next polyline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need some permuting of axes with `np.swapaxes` and a reshape -

```
poly_array.swapaxes(1,2).reshape(poly_array.shape[0],-1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [127]: poly_array
Out[127]: 
array([[[-0.707,  0.   ],
        [-0.371,  0.   ],
        [ 0.371,  0.   ],
        [ 0.707,  0.   ]],

       [[ 0.   , -0.707],
        [ 0.   ,  0.   ],
        [ 0.   ,  0.707],
        [ 0.   ,  0.   ]],

       [[ 0.707,  0.707],
        [ 0.928,  1.   ],
        [ 0.928,  0.707],
        [ 0.707,  0.   ]]])

In [142]: out
Out[142]: 
array([[-0.707, -0.371,  0.371,  0.707,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   , -0.707,  0.   ,  0.707,  0.   ],
       [ 0.707,  0.928,  0.928,  0.707,  0.707,  1.   ,  0.707,  0.   ]])

In [143]: out[:,1]
Out[143]: array([-0.371,  0.   ,  0.928])
```